# Address on US faxed ballot oath

Tags: us-citizens, elections

I am a US citizen who permanently moved abroad. As such, I am eligible to vote by fax. I received my ballot my snail mail with instructions for voting.

In the "Faxed ballot oath" document, I am asked for my "Residence Address". In this form, the country is pre-filled with the letters "U.S.A.".

Which address am I expected to write?

(The ballot is to be sent to the Los Angeles County, if it matters)

Comment: I don't really know the *correct* answer to this, but in my case I just gave my former address in the district that I was voting in. I think they just want it so they can route it to the correct office for your district. Not posting as an answer though since I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your inhabited last address in the US before you moved. IIRC it is used to determine your residency, and to make sure that your vote goes to the right state/county/whatever.

[Source](https://www.fvap.gov/info/laws/voting-residency-guidelines)